# Time Series on Oil Filter Pressure

Tags: time-series, residuals

I am not really strong with time series but I have a project I am working on..

I have a problem where I am trying to model a time series of the difference in pressure before and after oil has passed through an oil filter.  I am trying to see if this oil filter can go longer without being changed.  I also have data on the temperature of this oil.  The temperature of the oil is a strong indicator of Difference in Pressure, 'PD'.  I was thinking that I would like to remove the effect of the Temperature by modeling the residuals from a model with Temperature as a predictor and PD as the response.  Would this work?  Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . Not only can their be a dynamic response but anomalies may be present in the data suggesting the need for Intervention Detection schemes. ID can suggest Pulses/Level Shifts/Seasonal Pulses/Time Trends reflecting omitted deterministic structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds reasonable. With time series there's often the lag issue. Maybe the pressure change responds to temperature change with the delay of some structure in time.